# Measuring QGIS performance to render 1-bit tif raster grids?

Tags: qgis, performance

I notice that since weekly 2.17, it renders my 1-bit tif raster grids slower than 2.16, when I move viewport.
The new release 2.18 does the same as 2.17.
So I move back to 2.16.3.

Are there changes in the renderer that might cause this?

If yes, is there any how to configure to the old renderer?

Is this should be filed as a bug at http://hub.qgis.org/?

---

This bug has been fixed on 2016-11-4 0515 UTC by Martin Dobias.
The issue is closed now.

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15796

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the QGIS development team.

Comment: Report the issue. If it had been reported during 2.17, it might have been solved before the 2.18 release.

Answer (score 2):

This would turn out to be the OTF CRS Transformation regression in 2.18.0

I've already filed a bug report at
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15796

By the way, speaking of how to measure rendering time,
it is  located in Setting / Options / Rendering / Debug / "Map canvas refresh", then open View / Panel / Log Messages Panel.